# Using routes defined in imported modules in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, bower

Let's say I want to modularize my controller along with the its view to be a bower component. My idea is that I want to define the route on this module to respond to the '/login' url.

```
var routes = [
    {
        "key": "aes",
        "value": {
            "abstract": true,
            "url": "",
            "templateUrl": "modules/logincliente/views/common-layout.html",
            "controller": "commonLayoutController as commonLayoutC"
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "aes.loginCliente",
        "value": {
            "url": "/login",
            "views": {
                "content": {
                    "controller": "LoginClienteController as loginClienteC",
                    "templateUrl": "modules/logincliente/views/loginCliente.html"
                }
            }
        }
    }
];
```

So when I import this module into my application, should it work?  Right now my application is saying that the aes.loginCliente state does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should work but you have to register your states in `$stateProvider`.

It might not, however, work with abstract states if you want to define the `abstract` state in the "core" module loaded after the external one.

Try something like this:

```
// this module can be loaded externally, before the other one
angular.module('aes.loginClient', [])
.config(function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider.state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    "controller": "LoginClienteController as loginClienteC",
    "templateUrl": "modules/logincliente/views/loginCliente.html"     
  });
});


angular.module('aes', ['aes.loginClient'])
.config(function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "modules/home/views/home.html",
    controller: "commonLayoutController as commonLayoutC"      
  });
});
```

Comment: So, I cannot use abstract states while adopting this strategy, is that it? The project I am working indeed uses several abstract states...

Comment: Not sure, I have never tried out such configuration. But it would be reasonable - you are trying to refer to an abstract state before it is defined. A module should take care about all of views concerned with a module, including its abstract states.

Comment: It worked indeed. The temporary solution was to include the abstract state in the module (controller and view). Not sure if it would be possible to use the abstract state defined in another module.